# Pass javascript comments by Antlr parser

Tags: c#, antlr4

I'm writing C# project which parsing Javascript code and comments to , but i got the some problems with that (grammar for .g4 file was taken and copied from ECMAScript grammar totally). I'm tried next way:

I set the channel value from HIDDEN to 0

```
 MultiLineComment
   : '/*' .*? '*/' -> channel(0)
   ;
 SingleLineComment
   : '//' ~[\r\n\u2028\u2029]* -> channel(0)
   ;
```

When i run programm with an Antlr parser , so occurs unexpected error:

> line 1:0 extraneous input '/*some comment*/' expecting {, 
>   RegularExpressionLiteral, '[', '(', '{', ';', '++', '--', '+', '-',
>   '~', '!', 'null', BooleanLiteral, DecimalLiteral, HexIntegerLiteral,
>   OctalIntegerLiteral, 'break', 'do', 'typeof', 'new', ' var', 'return',
>   'void', 'continue', 'for', 'switch', 'while', 'debugger', 'funct ion',
>   'this', 'with', 'if', 'throw', 'delete', 'try', Identifier,
>   StringLiteral}

I'm some beginner in antlr , but i suspect what removing command line "-> skip" or similar command "channel->(HIDDEN)" from grammar rule (or sequence of tokens which does not affect the code) is only way for that parser can see that comments. But all the same help me: How to do so that parser don't ignore the comments(they were would saved by parser) and antlr don't output the **extraneous input error** during code validation by antlr ? If it is impossibly , then what rule construction i must add in my grammar file(How it looks like) which match any comments as before so after any lexical element: token , sequence of tokens , statement, expression e.t.c. ? In an case of emergency say: what chapter from Antlr4 manual says concretely
about a resolving of that task ? Recently i downloaded the Antlr4 book , but while i can't find exact answer there.

Comment: ANTLR4 book: "chapter 12.1 Broadcasting Tokens on Different Channels"

Comment: Thank you. I hope it helps )